# Updating 200,000+ rows containing UNC paths to a new host name in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We are replacing a file server in the business that has failed on us and in some tables in a SQL Server database there are approx. 200k records that have a column which stores an UNC file path to a file hosted on the old file server.

I am currently using the below code to achieve the update, unfortunately it fails complaining that the transaction logs are full and I end up having to restore the database.

```
DECLARE @currentServerName as nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @newServerName as nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @likeMatch as nvarchar(50)
SET @currentServerName = N'\\dom-fls-p01.localdom\';
SET @newServerName =     N'\\dom-filesrv.localdom\'; 
SET @likeMatch =     @currentServerName + '%';

UPDATE [DownloadQueue] 
SET [LocalPath] = @newServerName + SUBSTRING([LocalPath], LEN(@currentServerName)+1, LEN([LocalPath])-LEN(@currentServerName)) 
WHERE [LocalPath] LIKE @likeMatch

UPDATE [DetectionFile] 
SET [OriginalFileLocation] = @newServerName + SUBSTRING([OriginalFileLocation], LEN(@currentServerName)+1, LEN([OriginalFileLocation])-LEN(@currentServerName)) 
WHERE [OriginalFileLocation] LIKE @likeMatch

UPDATE [FileTransferOperation] 
SET [TargetPath] = @newServerName + SUBSTRING([TargetPath], LEN(@currentServerName)+1, LEN([TargetPath])-LEN(@currentServerName)) 
WHERE [TargetPath] LIKE @likeMatch

UPDATE [WorkQueue] 
SET [Location] = @newServerName + SUBSTRING([Location], LEN(@currentServerName)+1, LEN([Location])-LEN(@currentServerName)) 
WHERE [Location] LIKE @likeMatch
```

Can anyone suggest a better method to achieve my goal?

Thanks,

Xavier.

Ps. yes we are changing it to a new CName that way future replacements doesn't need database updates :)

Comment: what is your recovery model?

Comment: It's currently set to Full. I am not against changing it if recommended. I also feel the need to mention that it's running at Compatibility level 90 (2005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of the following solutions

1. Take a Log backup of the database before starting the `UPDATE`. Take a log backup after all `UPDATES` are complete. you could since there is no transaction boundary (`BEGIN TRAN`, `COMMIT`) run these independently, you can take a log backup after each of the `UPDATE` statement. Something like this.

   ```
   UPDATE [DownloadQueue] SET [LocalPath] = @newServerName + SUBSTRING([LocalPath], LEN(@currentServerName)+1, LEN([LocalPath])-LEN(@currentServerName)) WHERE [LocalPath] LIKE @likeMatch
   ```

   Run Log backup

   ```
   BACKUP LOG <DatbaseName>
   ```

   Next Update Statement

   ```
   UPDATE [DetectionFile] SET [OriginalFileLocation] = @newServerName + SUBSTRING([OriginalFileLocation], LEN(@currentServerName)+1, LEN([OriginalFileLocation])-LEN(@currentServerName)) WHERE [OriginalFileLocation] LIKE @likeMatch
   ```

   Run Log backup

   ```
   BACKUP LOG <DatbaseName>
   ```

   and so on...
2. Change to Simple recovery model and run the `UPDATE`. Switch back to a full recovery model and take a full backup.
3. If `Update` still fails due to transaction log space after switching to Simple recovery model. You can alternatively try to Run the `Update` in a batch. take a batch size, say 10k records and run the `UPDATE` for the specific batch, issue a `CHECKPOINT` then and then continue to the next batch.
4. If all else fails, Increase the Log File Space

Comment: this looks positive, I will be in a position to test in about 30 minutes when we have an outage planned. I will let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to backup & truncate the tlogs before running this.  It would also help to increase the max log size if possible.

If it's still unable to complete, run it in batches (`Update top (10000)`) until the logs fill up, backup the logs again, repeat until complete.

Comment: I will see if I can get the log size allowed increased, I will also use that update top suggestion too